# Keyboard flickers when back is pressed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am starting to learn flutter and I have 2 screens MyHome vs NewScreen.
When I press back from NewScreen to MyHome, I notice there is a flicker and lag when the keyboard appears and I don't know how to fix it?
Can anyone fix it for me?, thanks

*MyHomePage*

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              TextField(
                autofocus: true,
              )
            ],
          ),
          FlatButton(onPressed: (){

            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NewScreen()));

          }, child: Text('New Screen'))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

New Screen

````
``` class _NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(autofocus: true,),
            FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Dialog Title'),
                    content: FlatButton(onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('CLick'),

                    ),
                  )
              );
            }, child: Text('Back to Home'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

Comment: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());` Add this inside onPressed. Flutter shows this type of behavior sometimes during navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add a focusNode to the textField and let the TextField be focussed in the initial state.

Adding an optional delay to it may help with the flickering aswel.

Do the same thing for the other file aswel.

```
class _NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {
late FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // optional add a delay before the focus happens.
    focusNode.requestFocus()

  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    focusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(focusNode: focusNode),
            FlatButton(onPressed: (){
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Dialog Title'),
                    content: FlatButton(onPressed: () {
                      focusNode.unfocus();              
                      //Possible delay to await the focusNode to unfocus
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Text('CLick'),

                    ),
                  )
              );
            }, child: Text('Back to Home'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```